# How to share config variables between different program languages?

Tags: php, node.js, variables, share, dotenv

How to share config variables between different program languages?

For example, if you have the following settings in php...

`define("URL", "http://google.com");`

How to get a variable called 'URL' in nodejs.

It's easy if you're on the same server, but how is it possible if you're on different servers?

Is this possible with redis or dotenv?
Is there a simple way without installation that I was not aware of?

Comment: Environment variables are a common method. Most languages provide a way to look up environment variables.

Comment: Store the data in a format that both languages can understand, eg: JSON, environment variables, etc.

Comment: If your question is about sharing in the verb sense, that is called orchestration. There are entire systems and services for this, or you can just copy and paste. If your question is about the noun, then use whatever is best for each system, with environment variables being a great (and my personal favorite) option. If your “config” is really “shared state”, which is a grey area, that’s a different story.

Comment: Variables to be shared are sensitive and have a lot of content, so it is not suitable as a 'rest api'.

As you said, "shared state" is appropriate.